# to finishing the back-end algorithms for an application, the Boolean logic needs to be refreshed. Which of the following statements is true?

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, boolean-logic

Prior to finishing the back-end algorithms for an application, the Boolean logic needs to be refreshed. Which of the following statements is true? O (4 < 5) and (6 > 7) O (1 == 2) or (2 == 2) O (-3>-1) or (-2 > 1)

Comment: You are expected to be able to do this in your head. It's not a programming problem. But if you aren't sure of the answers, just type these expressions at a Python prompt and see what the interpreter says.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

O (4 < 5) and (6 > 7) O (1 == 2) or (2 == 2) O (-3>-1) or (-2 > 1)\